# calculating the least amount routers needed to reach a set of buildings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have range = n and  a numlist x = [2,4,5,6,7,9,11,12] and another numlist y = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14] (from range 0 to max(x) + n + 1) and I want to output the least amount of routers I would have to put to reach the buildings in numlist x and on which building I would put them on (I would only put them on buildings in numlist x) given that each router had the range n. If range here was 2 then a router on building 2 would only reach buildings 2 and 4. If I had a router on building 6 then the router would reach buildings 4,5,6,7,8 and so on. (the buildings from numlist x are the ones that matter, numlist y is only there as a reference). So far I have this.

```
needed_towers = [2,4,5,6,7,9,11,12]
towers =  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14] #only used here to get the intersect between the needed towers and towers so i can remove the unneeded numbers from the dictionary values 
intersect = set(towers) - set(needed_tows)

r = 2
ans = []
placed = {}
a = [list(range(i-r,i + r + 1)) for i in needed_tows]

for i in a:
    for j in intersect:
        if j in i:
            i.remove(j)

for i,x in zip(needed_tows,a):
    placed[i] = x

#if needed_tows was [1,2,3,4,5] one of the solutions would be 2,5 or 2,4 and a few other solutions but i only need one.
```

this program just calculates which buildings a router would reach if it were placed on each building and places the values in a dictionary, the next step would be to calculate what the buildings i need to place them on. technically there are many solutions to this such as [4,9,12] or even [4,9,11] and a few more but as long as its the shortest solution possible it doesn't matter. How do I write a program to calculate which buildings I would have to place routers on so each building is reached?

Comment: I'm no graph theory wizard, but I think your problem statement is a version of the _minimum vertex cover_ problem, which is NP-Hard.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I'm not very familiar with graphs but the original problem had nothing to do with graphs really, but to provide further context, the original problem was that the numlist x I mentioned above was a set of skyscrapers and a company wanted a program to figure out the least amount of routers needed to reach all skyscrapers in  numlist x with a given variable as a range for all routers. the coding problem wanted the minimum amount of routers needed and where to place them (in the sample cases given, all of them have multiple possible answers so you just output any 1 answer that works)

Comment: A greedy approach would work. Set the first router in the building with the biggest number that will cover all building preceding it. Then remove all buildings covered by this router from the list and continue with the reminder of the list in the same way.

Comment: @bb1 I thought of doing that at first but my main problem was that some placements would reach the exact same buildings as a different placement (hence the variant solutions) so I wasn't sure how I'd go about writing it and how the code would work with multiple possible answers as I'm not experienced with these sort of problems. Do you have a demonstration you could show?

Comment: Do you need all possible answers, or just the fastest way to find *an* (optimal) answer? Also, you say "If range here was 2 then a router on building 2 would only reach buildings 2 and 4" - wouldn't a router with `r == 2` on building 2 reach buildings `[1, 2, 3]`? I assume `towers` are the buildings and `needed_tows` here are buildings that can have towers? (the naming isn't clear, or doesn't match the logic)

Comment: @Grismar you only need 1 solution also what I said about router on building 2 reaching 2 and 4 was only for the needed towers. it reaches 0,1,2,3,4 but 2 and 4 are the only ones necessary since they're the ones in the needed tower list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from bisect import bisect

x = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12]
r = 2

out = []
while x:
    idx = -1 if (n := x[0] + r) > x[-1] else bisect(x, n) - 1
    out.append(x[idx])
    x = x[bisect(x, out[-1] + r):]

print(out)
```

It gives:

```
[4, 9, 12]
```

Comment: Thank you this works! Can you elaborate a bit on how this operates? I don't get what bisect does here.

Comment: Just wondering ... is there a counter example where this greedy algorithm does not produce an optimum solution?

Comment: @rickhg12hs This will always give the minimal number of routers. You can prove it by induction with respect to the length of the list of towers `x`. The idea is that the greedy placement of the first router covers the biggest possible segment at the beginning of the list. If you place the first router (i.e. the one covering the beginning of the list) differently, then the tail of the list that must be covered by other routers will be at least as long as the tail produced by the greedy algorithm. But a longer tail will require at least as many routers as the shorter one.

Comment: @CSuser The code implements the greedy approach that I described in the comment under the question. `bisect()` is used to find indices of the right elements of the list `x`. For example, `bisect(x, x[0] + r)` returns the index where the element  `x[0] + r` should be inserted in the list `x` if the ordering of this list is to be preserved. As a consequence, `bisect(x, x[0] + r) - 1` is the index of the biggest element of `x` which is smaller or equal to `x[0] + r`. The element at this index is where we place the first router.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  If the problem was expanded to two dimensions, i.e., each building had an `x,y` coordinate, would this greedy approach still be optimum?  Is that problem a _dominating set_ problem?

Comment: @rickhg12hs This is a dominating set problem for a graph where nodes are buildings and there is an edge between any two buildings that are at the distance smaller or equal to  `r`. The simple greedy algorithm (always pick the node with the biggest numbers of uncovered neighbors) in general does not give an optimal solution even in the 1-dimensional case. It is possible though that some its variant will work in the 2-dimensional case just as it works in the 1-dimensional setting.